# Intellij IDEA - Gradle Error:org.gradle.listener.ListenerBroadcast.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

On Ubuntu (14) using Intellij IDEA (15.0.2), when "Refresh all gradle projects" for Gradle (2.9) or running any of its tasks it gives the following exception:

```
Error:org.gradle.listener.ListenerBroadcast.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V
```

im able to run gradle tasks from command-line, i also tried this after cleaning and rebuilding, any ideas?

If i use gradle --refresh-dependencies will i have the same effect from command-line as "Refresh all gradle projects" from IDEA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from Intellij users forum, to update to the latest version of IntelliJ, so i switch to 2016.1, the bug as been fixed in this version.